# Randomly select one of two ImageViews and update ResourceImage

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have created in my layout two ImageViews, let's call them `imageviewTop` and `imageviewBottom`.
I saved two images into the drawable (green_image.png and red_image.png).
I also added a button and want I would like to do is, when the button is clicked, one of the ImageViews will get selected randomly and from the green_image it will change to the red_image.

I already tried with creating a switch/case statement and generating a random number, like 1 or 2.
Based on this number the case statement would update either the top or bottom image.
This is working fine for 2 ImageViews, but in case I would have 100, I would need to create 100 cases in code.
I am searching for a more dynamic option.

I know how to update the image for the ImageView, I am struggling with the part, on how to select one ImageView randomly, if it is possible.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imagevieTop, imageviewBottom;
    Button randomButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagevieTop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTop);
        imageviewBottom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewBottom);
        randomButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRandom);

        randomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // randomly select one of the two imageviews
                // for example: randomly selected imageviewTop
                // set imageresource red_image to imageviewTop

                //at next start up it would select either top or bottom, 50%-50% and then assign the image to it
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just simply random generate the coordinate of ImageView and the image inside it?
OR
You may simply write some code like
int a = new Random().nextInt(100);
x = (x - x % 4)/4 * multiple;
y = x % 4 * multiple;
imgId = a;
then simple set the images' coordinate and image

Comment: I would like to set the images already upfront, so for example on start up there should always be 4 green images at specific coordinates and at button click one of them turns red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use one ImageView, and randomize the picture you draw.

Alternatively, you could adjust this to use an array of ImageViews. Your choice.

The line you want, though, is `int index = random.nextInt(imgs.length);` to get a random index from the list.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int[] imgs = new int[] { R.drawable.green_image, R.drawable.red_image };
    Button randomButton;

    private final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        randomButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRandom);

        randomButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int index = random.nextInt(imgs.length);

                // randomly select one of the two drawables
                int resId = imgs[index];

                // set imageresource imgView
                Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
                imgView.setImageDrawable(d);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

To handle the "100 ImageViews" problem, I'd recommend not copying 100 lines of code, and instead looping over reasonable ID values.

```
List<ImageView> imgViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("imgView" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    ImageView nextImg = (ImageView) findViewById(resId);
    imgViews.add(nextImg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am checking right now if it works, together with the answer below I might be able to create an ArrayList, loop through it and then randomly select one and update. Will give feedback in a few minutes.

Comment: It worked perfectly together with the answer josemgu91, with the random imageview select. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do a dynamic selection of "n" ImageView elements, then you'll need to store them in a data structure (e.g. an array, a list, etc.). For example this code will select a random ImageView from a list:

```
public ImageView getRandomImageView(final List<ImageView> imageViewList) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        //The "nextInt" method works in the half-open range [0, n), so it'll never be equal to the list size.
        final int randomElement = random.nextInt(imageViewList.size());
        return imageViewList.get(randomElement);
    }
```

In your case, with two ImageView's ("imagevieTop" and "imageviewBottom") declared in fixed variables then you would need to pass them to a list or something similar in order to select one of them dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying it out together with the answer from above/below.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked. I used the code to populate an ArrayList with the imageviews provided by cricket_007 and then used yours to select one of them randomly and updated. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help you =).